# How to selectively disable checkers for certain file types when using syntastic in vim?

Tags: vim, plugins, configuration, syntastic, syntax-checking

For example, HTML partial templates are being flagged with tons of errors but they are supposed to be fragments of a complete HTML doc.

Comment: Try `:help syntastic-quickstart` and `:help 'syntastic_mode_map'`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:syntastic_mode_map = {
    \ "mode": "active",
    \ "passive_filetypes": ["go"] }
```

This sets Syntastic to active mode (checks are made on save or open) but not for, in this case, Go files, which will be checked only when explicitly running `:SyntasticCheck`. Just change the array of `passive_filetypes` to whatever you need.

Comment: Is this the correct way to specify the array? `"passive_filetypes": ["go", "html"]` ?

Answer (score 1):

In `.vimrc` to ignore `.env` file for example:

```
let g:syntastic_ignore_files = ['.env']
```

From the `:help syntastic`:

> Use this option to specify files that syntastic should never check. It's a
> list of |regular-expression| patterns. The full paths of files (see |::p|) are
> matched against these patterns, and the matches are case-sensitive. Use |\c|
> to specify case-insensitive patterns. Example:
>
> `let g:syntastic_ignore_files = ['\m^/usr/include/', '\m\c\.h$']`

There's also another one, `syntastic_<filetype>_<checker>_quiet_messages`:

> Finally, variables 'g:syntastic___quiet_messages' can
> be used to filter out some of the messages produced by specific checkers. The
> effect is identical to that of |syntastic_quiet_messages|, except only messages
> from the corresponding checkers are filtered. Example: >
>
> `let g:syntastic_python_pylama_quiet_messages = {"type":  "style","regex": '\m\[C03\d\d\]' }`

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to edit the settings for your particular HTML linter/checker but you can also add the following to your .vimrc or enter as a command:

`au BufNewFile,BufRead *.html set b:syntastic_skip_checks = 1`

au is autocommand, such that when a .html buffer is opened, syntastic skips checking it. The `b:` prefix only applies to the current buffer.

Comment: This works, sort of, but it definitely isn't how you're supposed to do it, and it also isn't the proper use for `b:syntastic_skip_checks`.  Read about passive filetypes in the manual instead.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Am I right in assuming that the arrays of types in `syntastic_mode_map` can be used to define just the exceptions to active checking ?